# Will each Graphql Subscription from same browser create one websocket connection?

Tags: graphql

I know what is [graphql subscription](https://docs.scaphold.io/tutorials/realtime-apps-with-subscriptions/).

My question is if each subscription will create one websocket connection? 
Or all the subscription from each browser is combined to one websocket connection?

I couldn't find answer anywhere in document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL itself purposefully does not specify a transport layer in the specification. Therfore the answer depends on the implementation that you are using but for the implementations it makes sense to have only one connection. In Apollo you can use [apollo-link-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-ws) to connect to the server. This link then creates (an keeps alive) a single socket to the server using [subscriptions-transport-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws). It can also handle all GraphQL methods (not only subscriptions) using the web socket.